# React MUIDatatables - How to display the name of tableMeta rowData

Tags: reactjs

How to display the name of tableMeta rowData.
How can I solve this problem!

```
<Tooltip title={"edit"}>
     <IconButton classes={{ root: classes.root }} onClick={() => console.log(tableMeta.rowData)}>
           EditIcon />
      </IconButton>
</Tooltip>
```

```
columns = [
        {
            label: "eid",
            name: 'id',
        },
        {
            label: 'Star time',
            name: 's_date',
        },
        {
            label: 'End time',
            name: 'e_date',
        },
]
```

console.log Now Data:

```
0: 1
1: "2018-06-01T00:00:00"
2: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
```

I want the console.log result:

```
id: 1
s_date: "2018-06-01T00:00:00"
e_date: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
```

Comment: Your object collection data format is wrong (columns)

Comment: I don't understand the meaning, I have corrected my article.